# Spring MVC - Model object not returning to view from controller- JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm writing a simple hello world program in spring mvc, where i'm passing an object to the view. The JSP page is opening properly, but its not getting the value which has been set in the controller and there are no errors in eclipse console. here is my code

```
@Controller
public class CncController {
String message = "Welcome to Spring MVC!";

@RequestMapping("/hello")
public ModelAndView showMessage(
        @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {
    System.out.println("in controller");

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("helloworld");
    mv.addObject("welcomeMessage", "Welcome to first page");
    System.out.println(mv);
    return mv;
}
}
```

### cnc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd     
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">


<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"></bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.cnc.cnccontroller" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

The JSP page is put under the web-inf folder correctly..

It is just showing

```
Hello {welcomeMessage}
```

Is there anything missing in the flow?

Comment: add your `web.xml` and the concerning jsp.

Comment: Change to Hello ${welcomeMessage}

Comment: @Sam, super.. Got it. :) Answer it, I will accept as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSP reference to the Model object should be within `${}`. In your case, it should be "Hello `${welcomeMessage}`"